# Add Meta tags for dynamic ecommerce website from cms for better seo

Tags: php, seo, meta-tags

I have an ecommerce cms in php which is used to add pages, categories and products. Now I want to ask that what logic will be used to store meta information for each product, category or page in database and how can I use that meta information stored in database for seo. I have attached screen shot for better understanding.
[image]

I am looking for something like this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem ?

Comment: The logic is just going to be "Here is some meta data, it is associated with this thing" and "We have this thing, get the associated meta data from the database and put it in the page".

Comment: #RKV Basically I am looking to add meta information for dynamically added content to that I can use it for better seo.

Answer (score 0):

Meta keywords is just keywords chain separated by coma, like - Big boobs, naked girl, underwear.

Meta description is item description, which will be shown in search engine search results. This must be short and describe what is on the page -not just keywords, but some human readable format.

Sorry if understood your question wrong :/

Update:
What is "Dynamically added" content in your case? Are you using some script to import data to your website? if yes - Check what fields in database are responsible for your meta data, and fill them with import directly with needed keywords and meta descriptions, which will be decided/generated in your script.

Comment: For dynamically added pages how can I add and use Meta Information?